# How to use a scanner (BlueJ)

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, bluej

I'm new to java and my task is to use a scanner to read in an array and an int in another method.This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter n: ");
int sz = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter locations of stones: ");
int[] array = new int[sz];
for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
jump(array,sz);
}
```

The method I want to read from starts like this:

```
public static void jump(int [] array, int amtStone){
int x =0, moveOK =1, jumpedLoc =0, jumpedCount =1;
//x: counter, moveOK: when 1, it is ok to continue. Otherwise, the jump is impossible.
//jumpedLoc: to keep track of the current location of the rabbit
//jumpCount: to count the amount of jumps
while (x<amtStone)
{if(array[x+1]-array[x]<=50){
jumpedLoc = array[x+1];
jumpedCount++;}
}

if (moveOK ==1)
System.out.println(jumpedCount);
else
System.out.println("-1");

}
```

What I'm doing is to calculate the smallest number of jumps it takes for a rabbit to reach the other side of the river. The ints in the array represents distances of stones from the starting point as one side of the river, and another int represents the number of stones. The longest distance the rabbit can jump is 50.

for the input and output:

Enter n: 7(Input,number of stones in the river)
32 46 70 85 96 123 145(Input, distances between the stone and the starting point, the last number is the width of the river, i.e. the distance between the destination (the other side of the river)and the starting point)
Output: 3(This is the smallest number of times a rabbit can jump)

If it is not possible, the output is -1.

When I run the main method, after I input the int and the array, there is no output and the program didn't continue. I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: What output do you expect? Why?

Comment: What makes you think the problem is not at the `jump()` method? Do you get any exceptions? There is no problem with the code you have posted. Can you post the jump method?

Comment: Well, that's a long story. What I'm doing is to calculate the smallest number of jumps it takes to reach the last number(as the other side of the river) The ints in the array represents locations of stones in the river, and another int represents the number of stones. and the longest distance of jump is 50.

Comment: Ok please update the question, adding your `jump()` method definition and what it is supposed to do and what is the desired output, because the code you posted is working just fine. The input is parsed correctly

Comment: not here please. edit the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here `while (x<amtStone)`. You run into an infinite loop.
 It is not very clear what you want to do but you check if `x < amtStone`. But`x == 0` and `amtStone >= 1` (assuming you actually input some numbers) and you never seem to update any of those 2. 
So `x < amtStone` is allways `true` and you never break out of the loop.

Now i am not 100% sure what are you trying to achieve with your code But i think this is what you want:

```
public static void jump(int [] array, int amtStone){ 
    int x =0, moveOK =1, jumpedLoc =0, jumpedCount =1; 
    //x: counter, moveOK: when 1, it is ok to continue. Otherwise, the jump is impossible. 
    //jumpedLoc: to keep track of the current location of the rabbit 
    //jumpCount: to count the amount of jumps 

    while (x<amtStone){

    //complete the code here. {
        if(array[x+1]-array[x]<=50){ 
            jumpedLoc = array[x+1]; 
            jumpedCount++;
        } 
        amtStone--;
    }
    if (moveOK ==1) System.out.println(jumpedCount); 
    else System.out.println("-1"); 
}
```

Comment: hmm...so I need a line of x++ after the if statement?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but the extra part is this `amtStone--;` Again though this might be wrong. Since i am not very sure what you intent to do.

Comment: Besides, according to the if statement, I know the condition is wrong but I just failed to think another way of doing it...

Comment: I'll clarify my problem. just a second.